# How to use bind to apply some change to the database

Tags: asp.net, databound-controls

I'm Using `Eval` method in databound controls in ASP.NET.

The main difference between `eval` and `bind` is eval is read only, we can't change on database thing eval.

While using bind we can appply some change to the database.

Can you provide me an example where we can use Bind to apply some changes to Database?

Comment: Could you show the code you've written so far for applying changes to the database?

Comment: I have not written any code. Just want to know the difference with the Eval and Bind with an Example.Thanks you...